# Tmux freezes after copying and pasting from OS clipboard

Tags: tmux

I want to copy and paste contents from Tmux session to other application, So i used the following configuration in my ".tmux.conf" file (Debian based OS)

```
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -sel clipboard"

bind C-v run "tmux set-buffer \"$(xclip -o -sel clipboard)\"; tmux paste-buffer"
```

But after copying and pasting to other application, my Tmux session freezes!,but terminal works fine

what am i missing, and also I'm new to tmux, please help me with this

Comment: Maybe the problem is one of the commands stalls for reasons like in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1565081/432690). What if you use `xsel` instead of `xclip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/654729/1694825xclip)

tl;dr - Add `&>/dev/null` so that it reads:

```bash
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -i -sel clipboard &>/dev/null"
```

Which is necessary because xclip is waiting for more input from STDIN, which prevents tmux from receiving input.